# WPF, Linq to SQL, C# > How to Populate and Save A Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, combobox

Pulling my hair out. I've got a table 'Belts' with columns 'BeltID' and 'BeltColor'. I've got a Linq to SQL generated class, and am trying to populate a combobox and it's only partially working. Here's what I've got so far:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (DojoDataClassesDataContext conn = new DojoDataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var belts = (from b in conn.Belts
                    select b);

        cboBelt.DisplayMemberPath = "BeltColor";
        cboBelt.SelectedValuePath = "BeltID";
        cboBelt.ItemsSource = belts;
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<ComboBox Margin="101,0,57,97" Name="cboBelt" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path = Belt.BeltColor}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path = Belt.BeltID}" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

And of course there's the whole autogenerated Linq to SQL stuff in DojoDataClassesDataContext that I used to do the text box data binding without any problems (well, aside from it taking a while to figure it all out). At the moment, the combo box pulls up the text: TheNameOfMyProject.Belt as all the dropdown options but once selected it shows the correct belt color based on order.

Comment: What do you see in the Output window when this code executes?  Are there any binding failure messages?

Comment: @Robert: No binding failutres.
@Anthony: Adding .ToList() at end of query causes the query to print out inside the combo box. Strange,  I know. Changing the display doesn't do it.
@Jake: About to try your solution.

Comment: No dice Jake, I'm getting namespace type errors in the xaml and I can't figure it out that way. I'd hope there was a way to modify my query and/or xaml code to get it working as the rest of my project is coded in a similar style anyway. If I'm being obtuse, do tell me. I'm still learning.

Comment: Come to think about it, I don't even need to do any binding. If I can just fill the combo box with code, then I can fill the database using LINQ based on the value of the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this function:

```
public IEnumerable<Belt> GetBelts()
{
 return /* the belts you want */;
}
```

Put this in your Window.Resources:

```
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BeltObject"
                        MethodName="GetBelts"                                   
                        ObjectType="{x:Type database:Belts}">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
```

with:

```
<ComboBox Margin="101,0,57,97" Name="cboBelt" DisplayMemberPath="BeltColor" SelectedValuePath="BeltID" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BeltObject}}"/>
```

This is the cleanest way to do it with WPF. You're probably running into issues because your `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` are incorrect - these should be string values representing property names, not bindings to specific property values.

Answer (score 0):

***Couple of things:***

**looking at your linq to sql**
I am not posative, but I think you are never actually calling the query try adding .ToList to the end of your query.

**Try changing your display to:**

DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path = BeltColor}"

SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path = BeltID}"